Prove that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges to zero
Proof: We have $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ Then for $n>N$ we have that:
$|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0|\leq\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}=\epsilon$.
Is this proof valid?

$\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right\rvert=\frac{1}{n}$. Writing $\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right\rvert<\frac{1}{n}$ is not correct

@Lorago Sorry I forgot  the \leq

We want $N$ to be an integer.
Let $N= \lceil \frac1\epsilon \rceil$, thus, $N \ge \frac1\epsilon$
In this case, if $n > N$,
then $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0 \right|=\frac1n < \frac1N \le  \epsilon $

I have no idea why this was downvoted since it deals with a crucial failure of the OP's "solution". Personally I would (for completeness of the solution) added that $N$ exists by the Archimedean axiom.

@ancientmathematician Do you really need $N\in \mathbb{N}$? I thought that the archimedean axiom assures me the existence of n  $N \leq n$ for $N\in \mathbb{R},n\in \mathbb{N}$

Also, mention that you've corrected the other error, changing $<\frac1n$ to $=\frac1n.$ Yes, this is mentioned in comments, but comments are not guaranteed to persist.

@Arthr Strictly speaking the definition of limit of a sequence has $N$ an integer. But it is obviously a general property that if you find a real $N$ which works , you can find an integer which works. So it depends on how far you have gotten in studying limits. Most mathematicians would treat it as you do. However, this seems like a "beginner" limit question, so the reader may or may not already know this.
